# Python: getting nicer plots for dates

Tags: python, date, plot

I have this code:

```
xformatter = mdates.DateFormatter(r'%d.%m.%y')

fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()
fig.autofmt_xdate()
ax1.xaxis.set_major_formatter(xformatter)
ax1.plot(dates,followers, '.-')
ax1.set_ylabel('Follower')
plt.title(str(today()))
plt.grid()
fig.savefig(figPath)
```

and it gives me this plot:

[image]

As you can see there is an ugly gap between 22.01.21 and 01.02.21 and the dates don't extent all the way to the end. Has someone an idea how I can

1. make sure no such gaps occur, and
2. the last date is always under the last data point?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check [these](https://www.earthdatascience.org/courses/use-data-open-source-python/use-time-series-data-in-python/date-time-types-in-pandas-python/customize-dates-matplotlib-plots-python/) examples

I think this piece of code would help you

```
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.WeekdayLocator(interval=1))
```

Comment: Glad to know that!